# Differential operators and quasi-finite morphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, d-modules

Let $ X, Y $ be smooth affine varieties over $ \mathbb C $.  Let $ T : X \rightarrow Y $ be a dominant quasi-finite morphism and let $ T^\# : \mathbb C[Y] \rightarrow \mathbb C[X] $ be the resulting map on coordinate rings.

($ T $ being quasi-finite means that it can be factored as an open embedding followed by a finite morphism.  It also means that $T^\# $ is injective and every element of $\mathbb C[X] $ is algebraic over $ \mathbb C[Y] $.)

Let $ D(X) $ denote the ring of differential operators on $ X $.  Is the following statement is true?

> Let $ d \in D(X) $.  Suppose that $ d(T^\#(f)) = 0 $ for all $ f \in \mathbb C[Y] $.  Then $ d = 0 $.

Comment: I guess you want to add the condition that $T$ is dominant for $T^\#$ to be injective (otherwise a closed embedding is an example of a quasi-finite morphism).

Comment: I agree and made the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: I think skipped a step in the original argument - it is not immediately clear to me that $d$ commutes with $\mathbb C[Y]$ in $D(X)$ unless $d$ is a derivation. I have added an inductive argument for this below.

---

I believe this is true. Here is a sketch of an argument.

We will prove this by induction on the degree of the differential operator $d$. It is certainly true for differential operators of degree 0.

Suppose $d\in D(X)$ is of degree $\leq k$, and $d(f)=0$ for all $f\in \mathbb C[Y]$ (which I identify with a subring of $\mathbb C[X]$).

**Lemma**: *We have $[d,f]=0$ for all $f\in \mathbb C[Y]$.*

**Proof of lemma:** The differential operator $[d,f]$ is of order $\leq k-1$, and $[d,f](g)=0$ for all $g\in \mathbb C[Y]$. The lemma now follows from the inductive hypothesis.

It remains to show that any $\mathbb C[Y]$-linear differential operator $d\in D(X)$ is zero.

Consider the finite field extension $$K := \mathbb{C}(Y) \subseteq L := \mathbb{C}(X)$$

Note that $D(X)$ injects in to $D(L/\mathbb C)$ and $d$ lands in the subring $D(L/K)$. In other words $d$ may be considered as an element of the ring $D(L/K)$ (here I am using Grothendieck's definition of differential operators for a $K$-algebra).

I claim that $D(L/K)=L$, and thus $d=0$. Indeed, $L$ is a smooth $K$-algebra of dimension $0$ (as we are in characteristic $0$), and thus:

1. The ring of $D(L/K)$ is generated by derivations $Der_K(L,L)$ and $L$.
2. $Der_K(L,L)=0$.

Comment: This looks good to me.  Thanks!  Can you provide a reference for the last two facts?

Comment: According to a comment by Mariano Suarez-Alvarez in an answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1974919/algebra-of-differential-operators , there is a proof of Fact 1 in the last chapter of McConner and Robson's book Noncommutative Noetherian Rings. However, I can't seem to get access to a copy at the moment to check.

Comment: Fact 2 is much more elementary. It is equivalent to the assertion that $\Omega^1_{L/K}=0$, which in turn is equivalent to the fact that $L/K$ is separable (immediate in characteristic $0$). The wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_differential#Unramified_and_smooth_morphisms indicates that there is a reference in Milne's book on etale cohomology, for example.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, I think that I know how to prove Fact 2.